# How the sum of individual numerical values should be equal to the parent value in the array?

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to set a logic and calculate some values but the calculation seems to be wrong.

**UPDATE :**

Let me explain, For instance I have [23,11,39] etc a series of values in an array and then in next array I am dividing these values into 3 values for each value of the first array element as : for 23 I divided it into 3 values as 10,10,3 so the total sum of these 3 values is equal to back 23 and then same like the rest other values and then next I am calculating the values for all these with respect to 40 i.e that how much 23 is going to be in 40 and then the rest and then the same way for the divided values too so the problem is that the sum of the divided values should be equal to the parent calculated value for 40 but they are not when I sum them with each other. So that's the problem !

Can you people let me know what I am doing wrong and how it can be fixed?

Here is my code :

```
$data = [76,190,120,39,56,11,17,67,45,23,76,54];
$data_divided = [[32,14,30],[100,80,10],[50,40,30],[20,10,9],[6,40,10],[3,5,3],[10,4,3],[50,10,7],[30,10,5],[10,20,3],[30,40,6],[4,25,25]];

    $min = min($data);
    $max = max($data) - $min;
    $n_data = array();
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($data_divided as $value) {
        $n_value = (($data[$i] - $min) / $max)*40;
        $n0 = (($value[0] - $min) / $max)*40;
        $n1 = (($value[1] - $min) / $max)*40;
        $n2 = (($value[2] - $min) / $max)*40;
        $n_data[] = [$n_value => [abs($n0),abs($n1),abs($n2)], abs($n0)+abs($n1)+abs($n2) ];
        echo "Parent Value : ".$n_value."<br>";
        echo "n0 : ".abs($n0)."<br>";
        echo "n1 : ".abs($n1)."<br>";
        echo "n2 : ".abs($n2)."<br>";
        echo "n0+n1+n2 : ".(abs($n0)+abs($n1)+abs($n2))."<br><br><br>";
        $i++;
    }
```

Here is it's Output as :

```
Parent Value : 14.525139664804
n0 : 4.6927374301676
n1 : 0.67039106145251
n2 : 4.2458100558659
n0+n1+n2 : 9.608938547486


Parent Value : 40
n0 : 19.888268156425
n1 : 15.418994413408
n2 : 0.22346368715084
n0+n1+n2 : 35.530726256983


Parent Value : 24.357541899441
n0 : 8.7150837988827
n1 : 6.4804469273743
n2 : 4.2458100558659
n0+n1+n2 : 19.441340782123


Parent Value : 6.2569832402235
n0 : 2.0111731843575
n1 : 0.22346368715084
n2 : 0.44692737430168
n0+n1+n2 : 2.6815642458101


Parent Value : 10.055865921788
n0 : 1.1173184357542
n1 : 6.4804469273743
n2 : 0.22346368715084
n0+n1+n2 : 7.8212290502793


Parent Value : 0
n0 : 1.7877094972067
n1 : 1.340782122905
n2 : 1.7877094972067
n0+n1+n2 : 4.9162011173184


Parent Value : 1.340782122905
n0 : 0.22346368715084
n1 : 1.5642458100559
n2 : 1.7877094972067
n0+n1+n2 : 3.5754189944134


Parent Value : 12.513966480447
n0 : 8.7150837988827
n1 : 0.22346368715084
n2 : 0.89385474860335
n0+n1+n2 : 9.8324022346369


Parent Value : 7.5977653631285
n0 : 4.2458100558659
n1 : 0.22346368715084
n2 : 1.340782122905
n0+n1+n2 : 5.8100558659218


Parent Value : 2.6815642458101
n0 : 0.22346368715084
n1 : 2.0111731843575
n2 : 1.7877094972067
n0+n1+n2 : 4.0223463687151


Parent Value : 14.525139664804
n0 : 4.2458100558659
n1 : 6.4804469273743
n2 : 1.1173184357542
n0+n1+n2 : 11.843575418994


Parent Value : 9.608938547486
n0 : 1.5642458100559
n1 : 3.1284916201117
n2 : 3.1284916201117
n0+n1+n2 : 7.8212290502793
```

**EXPECTED OUTPUT :**

```
Parent Value : 14.525139664804
n0 : 4.6927374301676
n1 : 0.67039106145251
n2 : 4.2458100558659
n0+n1+n2 : 14.525139664804


Parent Value : 40
n0 : 19.888268156425
n1 : 15.418994413408
n2 : 0.22346368715084
n0+n1+n2 : 40


Parent Value : 24.357541899441
n0 : 8.7150837988827
n1 : 6.4804469273743
n2 : 4.2458100558659
n0+n1+n2 : 24.357541899441


Parent Value : 6.2569832402235
n0 : 2.0111731843575
n1 : 0.22346368715084
n2 : 0.44692737430168
n0+n1+n2 : 6.2569832402235


Parent Value : 10.055865921788
n0 : 1.1173184357542
n1 : 6.4804469273743
n2 : 0.22346368715084
n0+n1+n2 : 10.055865921788


Parent Value : 0
n0 : 1.7877094972067
n1 : 1.340782122905
n2 : 1.7877094972067
n0+n1+n2 : 0


Parent Value : 1.340782122905
n0 : 0.22346368715084
n1 : 1.5642458100559
n2 : 1.7877094972067
n0+n1+n2 : 1.340782122905


Parent Value : 12.513966480447
n0 : 8.7150837988827
n1 : 0.22346368715084
n2 : 0.89385474860335
n0+n1+n2 : 12.513966480447


Parent Value : 7.5977653631285
n0 : 4.2458100558659
n1 : 0.22346368715084
n2 : 1.340782122905
n0+n1+n2 : 7.5977653631285


Parent Value : 2.6815642458101
n0 : 0.22346368715084
n1 : 2.0111731843575
n2 : 1.7877094972067
n0+n1+n2 : 2.6815642458101


Parent Value : 14.525139664804
n0 : 4.2458100558659
n1 : 6.4804469273743
n2 : 1.1173184357542
n0+n1+n2 : 14.525139664804


Parent Value : 9.608938547486
n0 : 1.5642458100559
n1 : 3.1284916201117
n2 : 3.1284916201117
n0+n1+n2 : 9.608938547486
```

Comment: what expected outcome you want? show us in array format

Comment: @AlivetoDie : I want the `$n0+$n1+$n2` value to be equal to `$n_value`

Comment: @AlivetoDie Also if possible so please I don't want the least value to be 0 with me but more than 0 for `$n_value`

Comment: Actually then you will get empty array. because there is no match found:- https://eval.in/852182

Comment: It's wrong now as you can see now for 11 value I am getting calculated value as 0 which is wrong I should be getting more than 0, That's what I want as well!

Comment: @AlivetoDie : I do know that it's not equal so I want it to be equal to each other

Comment: @mickmackusa : Updated the question. Please have a look over it again.

Comment: OK Sure I will post expected output result!

Comment: @AlivetoDie I have updated the question with Expected OUTPUT. Please have a look over it again

Comment: @mickmackusa :  I have updated the question with Expected OUTPUT. Please have a look over it again

Comment: It would be a miracle if those three float values added up to the desired value.  Your task is impossible in its current form.  You will need to change your process or declare an acceptable margin or error due to rounding.  I have another question: can any of the initial `$data_divided` values be zero?  If not I can suggest a different `$min` formula to eliminate the need for `abs ()`.

Comment: @UmairShahYousafzai  i am agreed to mickmackusa. How those three values added and will five desired output? clearly by eyes you can see that those three values will not give desired output when they add-up

Comment: @mickmackusa Yes indeed I don't want the value to be 0 only when the value itself is 0 in the parent array for the relevant element.

Comment: @AlivetoDie : That's exactly What I want to do, You can go ahead and change the formulas accordingly, That is no problem but the values should be equal to the parent calculated value.

Comment: @UmairShahYousafzai Can you explain the reasoning behind your current formula?  Why exactly are you subtracting `$min`, then dividing by `$max` then multiplying by `40`?  What are you actually measuring in this project?  What is the necessary decimal specificity for this assignment?  Would integers as a result be fine?  or do you need values to 2 decimal places?  or 8 places? or other?

Comment: @mickmackusa : Let me explain I am generating my own SVG based LINECHART's so if the Coordinates point values goes higher than 40 so then I can't see the peaks of the LINECHART points so due to that issue I can't bear higher values than 40 so that's why I am regenrating the array of the values according to 40 value so that I have maximum 40 value in the array and the rest is set accordingly to 40 value.So the formula does that exactly. And yes it's no problem you can have as many decimal places but the divided values should be positive values and also their sum must equal to `$n_value` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my recommendation...

Reduce all data in both arrays by a factor which will produce only values between `0` and `40`.  To improve the chances of having a clean relationship between the expected total value (`$data`) and the sum of the split values (`$data_divided`), I suggest rounding the factor UP to the next integer (`ceil()`).  In doing this, you no longer need to damage your `$divided_data` with subtraction or `abs()`.

My demonstration will store and display the initial values, calculated values, and the mathematical difference between them.  As you will see in my comments and output, only the subarray with the index `9` will not be an exact match -- I believe this is a mere typo.

All of the calculated data is within the acceptable range with a max of `38` and a min of `0.6`  This approach will not guarantee a max value of `40` but it will give your data I very good chance of adding up exactly.  If you remove the `ceil()` function from the `$factor` formula, you will notice `40` becomes possible but also some of the values "fray" (some worse than others).

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/9fcd2a78215453a0500abdee2d0e3e728e49b37a))

```
$data = [76,190,120,39,56,11,17,67,45,23,76,54];
// notice flawed data-----------------^^

$data_divided = [[32,14,30],[100,80,10],[50,40,30],[20,10,9],[6,40,10],[3,5,3],[10,4,3],[50,10,7],[30,10,5],[10,20,3],[30,40,6],[4,25,25]];
// notice flawed data----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------^^^^^^^

$factor=ceil(max($data)/40); // 5 in this case (rounds up to a clean integer for future dividing)

$n_data = array();
foreach ($data_divided as $i=>$a) {
    $n_value=$data[$i]/$factor;  // reduce expected sum value
    $a=array_map(function($v)use($factor){return $v/$factor;},$a);  // reduce split values
    $sum=array_sum($a);  // sum the reduced split values
    $n_data[]=[
               "N_Value"=>$n_value,
               "Split"=>$a,
               "Sum"=>$sum,
               "Diff"=>$n_value-$sum  // find difference in calculated values
               ];
}
$data = $n_data;
var_export($data);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'N_Value' => 15.2,
    'Split' => 
    array (
      0 => 6.4,
      1 => 2.8,
      2 => 6.0,
    ),
    'Sum' => 15.2,
    'Diff' => 0.0,
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'N_Value' => 38.0,
    'Split' => 
    array (
      0 => 20.0,
      1 => 16.0,
      2 => 2.0,
    ),
    'Sum' => 38.0,
    'Diff' => 0.0,
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'N_Value' => 24.0,
    'Split' => 
    array (
      0 => 10.0,
      1 => 8.0,
      2 => 6.0,
    ),
    'Sum' => 24.0,
    'Diff' => 0.0,
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    'N_Value' => 7.8,
    'Split' => 
    array (
      0 => 4.0,
      1 => 2.0,
      2 => 1.8,
    ),
    'Sum' => 7.8,
    'Diff' => 0.0,
  ),
  4 => 
  array (
    'N_Value' => 11.2,
    'Split' => 
    array (
      0 => 1.2,
      1 => 8.0,
      2 => 2.0,
    ),
    'Sum' => 11.2,
    'Diff' => 0.0,
  ),
  5 => 
  array (
    'N_Value' => 2.2,
    'Split' => 
    array (
      0 => 0.6,
      1 => 1.0,
      2 => 0.6,
    ),
    'Sum' => 2.2,
    'Diff' => 0.0,
  ),
  6 => 
  array (
    'N_Value' => 3.4,
    'Split' => 
    array (
      0 => 2.0,
      1 => 0.8,
      2 => 0.6,
    ),
    'Sum' => 3.4,
    'Diff' => 0.0,
  ),
  7 => 
  array (
    'N_Value' => 13.4,
    'Split' => 
    array (
      0 => 10.0,
      1 => 2.0,
      2 => 1.4,
    ),
    'Sum' => 13.4,
    'Diff' => 0.0,
  ),
  8 => 
  array (
    'N_Value' => 9.0,
    'Split' => 
    array (
      0 => 6.0,
      1 => 2.0,
      2 => 1.0,
    ),
    'Sum' => 9.0,
    'Diff' => 0.0,
  ),
  9 => 
  array (
    'N_Value' => 4.6,
    'Split' => 
    array (
      0 => 2.0,
      1 => 4.0,
      2 => 0.6,
    ),
    'Sum' => 6.6,
    'Diff' => -2.0,
  ),
  10 => 
  array (
    'N_Value' => 15.2,
    'Split' => 
    array (
      0 => 6.0,
      1 => 8.0,
      2 => 1.2,
    ),
    'Sum' => 15.2,
    'Diff' => 0.0,
  ),
  11 => 
  array (
    'N_Value' => 10.8,
    'Split' => 
    array (
      0 => 0.8,
      1 => 5.0,
      2 => 5.0,
    ),
    'Sum' => 10.8,
    'Diff' => 0.0,
  ),
)
```